# How do nuclear membranes form during Telophase of Mitosis/Meiosis?

Tags: meiosis, mitosis, membrane

During Telophase, homologous chromosome pairs reach the poles of the cell with the help of microtubules. From there, nuclear membranes form around each new set of chromosomes.

My confusion originates from a single question: How did these nuclear membranes form around the chromosomes?

Comment: I think that is a great question, but as far as I know not a great deal is known about the process. The nuclear membrane, as depicted in textbooks, is contiguous with the endoplasmic reticulum. So when the nuclear envelope breaks down it would seem like the membrane components join a pool of structures poised to reform. In the first published experiments using nuclear extracts from the eggs of X. laevis, just adding purified DNA from bacteriophage lambda could enucleate membrane formation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this book](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9890/), during disassembly of the nuclear envelope, the nuclear membranes are broken down into vesicles. The nuclear membranes reform at the end of mitosis as the vesicles bind to the surface of chromosomes and fuse with each other to form a double membrane around the chromosomes (how this happens is not clear, except that integral membrane proteins and lamins may be involved, but physical contact is supposedly the first step).